# Get selected MenuItem props from Select (Material UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My display component

```
const myComponent = ({ title, data, errors, onSubmit, groups }) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState(
    Object.assign(
      {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        group: "",
        isAdmin: false,
      },
      data || {}
    )
const handleGroupChange = (event) => {

    console.log(event.target);
    setState({
      group: event.target.value
    })
  }

return (
<FormControl className={styles.formControl}>
          <InputLabel id="group-select">Groups</InputLabel>
          <Select
            id="group-select"  
            value={state.group}
            onChange={handleGroupChange}
            >
            {
              groups.length > 0 ? (
                groups.map((group) => {
                  console.log(group);
                  return <MenuItem key={group._id} id={group._id} value={group.name}>{group.name}</MenuItem>
              })
              ) : <MenuItem>No Groups</MenuItem>
            }
            </Select>
      </FormControl>
)
}
```

**Behavior**

`groups` is passed through the container component .I can access the `event.target.value`

{ value --> group.name,  name --> undefined }

**But**
I cannot access the `id` prop. I want both **id** and **value** props stored in `state.group`. I tried with `MenuItem` and `option` elements and `NativeSelect`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get id from each menu item and store in a state like this this.setState({
      group: { id: even.target.id, value:even.target.value
    }) Inside handleGroupChange And make sure to change state group as object type

Comment: event.target.id is undefined. `event.target` only has `value` & `name`

Comment: Okay, in handleGroupChange filter the groups array with e.target.value which is group name, you'll have entire object, then you can assign the entire object in state and use that value wherever you want to